# SalesForce - Fixing incorrect mine type for static JS file

Tags: javascript, salesforce

We are creating a salesforce visual app. But when we are uploading ant JS file inside the static resources the MIME TYPE is `text/plain` instead of `application/javascript` due to which app is failed to run and browser is giving `MIME TYPE mismach` error.

Please let me know if anyone knows how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To correct the mime type of the static resource within salesforce:

1. Retrieve the static resource using Metadata API (ANT or Force.com IDE)
2. Change contentType in resourcename--meta.xml

   `<contentType>application/x-javascript</contentType>`
3. Deploy the corrected static resource

Correct types for JS files are : `"application/javascript"`  or `"application/x-javascript"`

If your file had no extension or an incorrect extension, for example js included in a file with .txt extension, correct the extension and reupload the file, also fix the reference in VF to include the extension

NOTE: MIME type for uploaded resource might differ based on the browser being used to upload

- Chrome - application/javascript
- Firefox -application/x-javascript
- IE 11- application/octet-stream